# Spark Sql Pivot issue - Column is not iterable

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to pivot a data frame in pyspark. While doing so, I get a `column is not iterable error. Column "find_typ_J_8" has values "J" and "8", for each VBELN_7 value, either both J and 8 types present or only one of find_type present.`

Here is the sample dataframe I am working with:

```
   VBELN_7 |vbtyp_7|  find_J_8|find_typ_J_8|
+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|0x0x782x3v|      7|0032101161|           J|
|0n1t026y97|      7|0032645476|           J|
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
tmp5.groupBy(F.col("VBELN_7"),F.col("vbtyp_7")).pivot(F.col("find_typ_J_8"), ['J', '8']).agg(F.first(F.col("find_J_8"),False))
```

Comment: Try without the F.col:  `df.groupBy("VBELN_7", "vbtyp_7").pivot("find_typ_J_8",["J","8"]).agg(F.first("find_J_8"))`

Comment: Well I'll be gosh darned... I had the same problem and no idea why this behavior occurs.